# How to write a correct list from string (on website)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a community with supporters and I want to display them on a website. If they pay 50€ or more their name will be colored, for any other amount it will be white. I have two strings in the `JS` where I can insert the donators, I want all of them to be displayed side by side but it doesn't quite work :/

Here's my JS, CSS and HTML:

```js
var donators = [];
var donatorsColor = ["<p id='d'>Zalon</p>", "<p id='d'>RotaryCoast</p>"];

function donatorNames() {
    document.getElementById("donator").innerHTML = donatorsColor.join(" • ");
    document.getElementById("donator").innerHTML = donators.join(" • ").style.color;
}
```

```css
#d {
    color: #2890da;
}
```

```html
<div id="donatorbox">
  <h4>Unsere Unterstützer:</h4>
  <p id="donator"></p>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Many thanks in advance,
David :)

Comment: any two or more elements should not have the same **ID's**. In your code id ``d`` is present in two elements

Comment: `<p>` is a block element, if you want the names to be displayes side-by-side, you need to use an in-line element likke `<span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things needed to be fixed.

1. `<p>` is a **block** element, thus to show side by side you need a `<span>` tag.
2. `donators.join(" • ").style.color` make no sense, as `join` returns a string of array elements joined together.
3. `ID` of an element on a web page is unique. No two elements on the same page can have the same `ID`.
4. `donatorNames()` function needed to be ended with `}`.

```js
var othersDonators = ["<span class='o'>John</span>", "<span class='o'>Mike</span>"];
var donatorsMoreThan5 = ["<span class='d'>Zalon</span>", "<span class='d'>RotaryCoast</span>"];

function donatorNames() {
   document.getElementById("donator").innerHTML = donatorsMoreThan5
                                                .concat(othersDonators)
                                                .join(" • ")
  
}

donatorNames();
```

```css
body{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.box {
  background: #000;
}

.d {
  color: #2890da;
}

.o {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h4>Our supporters(Unsere Unterstützer):</h4>
  <div id="donator"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much :) Is there a way to put both donator-groups in the same div? So that the donators are mixed and the 'special ones' get highlighted

Comment: @DavidB I have updated the code, have a look

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that need fixing:

1. `<p>` is a *block* element; if you want the names to appear side-by-side you need to use an *inline* one (e.g. `<span>`)
2. `id`s must be unique in a document; you should change your `#d` ID to a `.d` class
3. You are missing a closing `}` for the `donatorNames()` function
4. the JavaScript line `donators.join(" • ").style.color;` makes no sense as `donators.join(" • ")` returns a string, not an HTML element, therefore `donators.join(" • ")` has no `style.color` property

A possible solution to your problem would be:

```js
var donators = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var donatorsVip = ["Zalon", "RotaryCoast"];

/*
 * Sorted only by VIP status (VIPs appear first)
 */
function donatorNames() {
  document.getElementById("donator").innerHTML = donatorsVip
    .map(item => (`<span class="d">${item}</span>`)) // add color to VIP donors
    .concat(donators) // add the non-VIP donors *after* the VIP ones
    .join(' • '); // convert the array into a string of donors, separated by ' • '
}

/*
 * Sorted by VIP status (VIPs appear first) AND alphabetically
 * NOTE: javascript will sort CAPITAL letters before lower case ones
 *       therefore 'Zalon' would appera before 'aaron'; this behaviour can be
 *       controlled by providing an appropriate sorting functioon to `Array.prototype.sort()`
 */
function donatorNamesSorted() {
  document.getElementById("donator2").innerHTML = donatorsVip
    .sort() // sort the VIP donors by alphabetical order 
    .map(item => (`<span class="d">${item}</span>`)) // add color to VIP donors
    .concat(donators.sort()) // add the alpabetically sorted non-VIP donors *after* the VIP ones
    .join(' • '); // convert the array into a string of donors, separated by ' • '
}

function load() {
  donatorNames();
  donatorNamesSorted()
}

load();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#donatorbox,
#donatorbox2 {
  color: #efefef;
}

.d {
  color: #2890da;
}
```

```html
<div id="donatorbox">
  <h4>Unsere Unterstützer:</h4>
  <p id="donator"></p>
</div>

<div id="donatorbox2">
  <h4>Unsere Unterstützer: (alphabetically sorted, VIPs first)</h4>
  <p id="donator2"></p>
</div>
```